# Symfony2 Form field Entity with 170k of results

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony

I have a form with a field of relationship entity.

The problem is that that entity tien a lot of records, over 170,000 and render the view form the server is saturated and no load.

What solutions are there to this?

This is the form field

```
        ->add('stream', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
            'class' => 'AcmeBundle:Stream',
            'property' => 'name',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'configs' => array(
                'multiple' => false,
                )
            )
        )
```

### IMPORTANT

I found something.

Stream entity is related to another entity under a bidirectional one-to-one.

Doctrine is running a query for each record to grab the data from that relationship.

Is there any way to tell Doctrine to not spread relationships and take "real" data Stream entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand you, you shoud look to `query_builder` options what allow you to fetch Streams what sutisfy some condition. E.g.:

```
->add('stream', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
            'class' => 'AcmeBundle:Stream',
            'property' => 'name',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'configs' => array(
                'multiple' => false,
                )
            'query_builder' => function (StreamRepository $repository) {
                     return $repository->findStreamsWhatSatisfySomeCondition();
                  }
        )
```

you can use external parameters like:

```
             'query_builder' => function (StreamRepository $repository) use ($param) {

              }
```

Detailed info you can find in [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder). Hope that will help find solution :)